# How to remove a limited number of characters before a . in a string?

Tags: r, wildcard

I am trying to write a function that turns "Bobson, Bob B." into "Bobson, Bob", but that would work for any middle initial. So far I have tried:

```
testName <- "Bobson, Bob B."

b1 <- gsub(" B\\.", "", testName)

b2 <- gsub(" *\\.", "", testName)

middle.initial <- paste0(" ","*","\\.")
b3 <- gsub(middle.initial, '', testName)
```

Of these, only b1 works. All the others return "Bobson, Bob B". From everything I've read about wildcard symbols, I would think that if b1 work, b2 should also work. I'm sure there is some kind syntax rule that I don't know about, but I just can't seem to find any examples.

I also tried gsub("**\.", "", testName) but that threw an error.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of similar questions with answers like

```
x <- c("Bobson, Bob B.", "Johnson, John J.")
gsub("(.*? .*?) .*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "Bobson, Bob"   "Johnson, John"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `*` is not a wildtype character in regular expressions, instead it means "match the preceding character zero or more times" - in the case of `" *\\."`, it is looking for zero or more blank spaces, followed by a period, which it dutifully replaces with `""`.

Instead, use: `b4 <- gsub(" [[:alpha:]]\\.", "", testName)`, which will replace any single letter preceded by a space and followed by a period.

Answer (score 0):

```
testName <- "Bobson, Bob B."

b2 <- gsub(" (\\w\\.)", "", testName)
```

The issue with your second attempt (b2) is that the pattern `" *\."` matches any number of spaces followed by a dot, but it doesn't take into account the specific initial you want to remove. This pattern will match any dot preceded by zero or more spaces, regardless of whether it's a middle initial or not.

In the above code, we are looking for a space followed by a single word character (middle initial) followed by a dot. By enclosing the middle initial in parentheses, it forms a capture group. The gsub function will replace the entire matched pattern (space + middle initial + dot) with an empty string, effectively removing the middle initial from the name.

```
# Output: "Bobson, Bob"
```